# Stabilizing Infrared Distance Sensor Output Values

Tags: c++, filter, arduino, infrared, numerical-stability

I'm reading infrared Sharp distance sensors:

http://www.robofun.ro/senzori/infrarosu/senzor_sharp_%20GP2D120XJ00F

With the reading I'm commanding a servo to direct the robot along a wall, a pretty simple map and write code.

The problem I'm having is that the sensor readings are way off, not behaving liniar... I know other people use these sensors just fine and I know they're wired just fine.

My question is how can I eliminate any oscillations sent to the servo? I'm getting 1 to 3 degrees of oscillations with the robot standing still at a fixed distance from the wall.

Below you have my code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;
int val; 
int val1;

int IRpin = A7;
 // analog pin for reading the IR sensor
void setup() {
 myservo.attach(3);

 Serial.begin(9600); // start the serial port
}
void loop() {
 float volts = analogRead(IRpin);

delay(100); 
val1 = map(volts, 230,500, 0 ,100);
 val = map(val1, 0, 100, 100, 80);
 myservo.write(val);
 Serial.println(val);
 }
```

Please note that double-mapping is necessary because, otherwise variations would be MUCH worse.

Thanks to anyone who will take the time to answer this and help me out...

LE: I've already considered hysteresis, but I want something that will not lose time with unnecessary readings and calculations.

Comment: I stumbled upon this on the Arduino Playground. It gave me the best results I've gotten so far. More Arduino users should know about this. http://arduino.cc/playground/Main/Smooth

Comment: Worth noting that a sharp ir sensor is not supposed to have a linear response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic control problem. I would recommend looking into PID controllers.

EDIT: sorry, misread the question. I thought you had a desired direction and were using the IR distance sensor to read your current direction. I'll leave the above up as background, but no it doesn't apply to this.

NEW ANSWER:

Sensor fluctuations are completely normal. You have to account for them. In this case I would use a simple moving averages filter. (your distance from the wall at any 1 time is the average of your last X sensor readings). Making x too big will introduce delays, too small and you will have the same noisy output.

In response to your LE note:
I don't think you can avoid some form of hysteresis when dealing with noisy inputs. Do you actually have a performance issue yet that you don't want to waste time on calculations? Don't pre-optimize.

EDIT 2: The above will smooth your input signal (current distance). How are you converting this to your output signal (servo setpoint) to achieve your desired distance (assuming you want to stay a fixed distance from a wall)? This is where a PID controller may help.

Comment: There is an issue with performance, since this is for a competition and the robot has to read several (quite a lot of) sensors at one time and process the data. I'll try with 5 readings and then averaging. Thanks a lot for your answer :D

Comment: @Eugen I doubt very much you would find a microcontroller with enough input pins for that many sensors for this to cause a performance issue. :)   I expanded on my answer a little bit as I realized you may also want to smooth your servo output signal.

Comment: to say filtering is not my area of expertise is an understatement, but (similar to the D in PID control), you can do a more complex filter that looks at the differences in past values as well as the average IF the real value, due to movement, may change significantly over the sample range.  That way you try to catch real changes and eliminate some of the lag.  However you also will overshoot some and could get wild oscillations if you don't choose the weighting variables correctly.  But if you move a tiny amount in say, 5 sensor readings, then just go with Tyson's answer!